# occurrences of two columns in a line UNIX command line

Tags: unix, awk

I'm having the following file:

```
epd cvrA
epd cvrA
cvrA epd
emrY hofB
mdtI ydeP
ygcH yagR
nrdD abrB
lsrK yqgD
yhdA yiaF
fadJ plsB
fadJ thiG
plsB thiG
ybhS glnE
yfeX idnR
```

I want to determine the occurrences of a combination of the values of both columns. So having A and B as well as B and A should count as the same. I tried a bit with uniq -c, but that didn't solve it. So in the end I want to have a file with each possible combination - again A and B and B and A should be summed up together. Is this possible with awk?

As for the output that would mean:

```
epd cvrA 3
emrY hofB 1
mdtI ydeP 1
ygcH yagR 1
nrdD abrB 1
lsrK yqgD 1
yhdA yiaF 1
fadJ plsB 1
fadJ thiG 1
plsB thiG 1
ybhS glnE 1
yfeX idnR 1
```

Comment: Post expected output

Comment: Something like this? `awk 'c[$1<$2?$1" "$2:$2" "$1]++;END{for(i in c)print i,c[i]}' file`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I updated the question for an expected output. Yeah a count would be nice in the third column, that I can sort then afterwards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ awk '{cnt[($1>$2 ? $1 FS $2 : $2 FS $1)]++}
       END{for (idx in cnt) print idx, cnt[idx]}' file
ygcH yagR 1
thiG plsB 1
hofB emrY 1
plsB fadJ 1
yqgD lsrK 1
ydeP mdtI 1
yfeX idnR 1
ybhS glnE 1
thiG fadJ 1
nrdD abrB 1
epd cvrA 3
yiaF yhdA 1
```

and if you want the output sorted by count, with GNU awk for sorted_in:

```
$ awk '{cnt[($1>$2 ? $1 FS $2 : $2 FS $1)]++}
       END{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_desc"; for (idx in cnt) print idx, cnt[idx]}' file
epd cvrA 3
thiG plsB 1
hofB emrY 1
plsB fadJ 1
yqgD lsrK 1
ydeP mdtI 1
yfeX idnR 1
ybhS glnE 1
thiG fadJ 1
nrdD abrB 1
ygcH yagR 1
yiaF yhdA 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Like this? Please post expected output and working data set.

```
$ cat > bar
a b
b a
$ awk '{if($1<$2) a[$1 " " $2]++; else a[$2 " " $1]++} END {for(i in a) print i, a[i]}' bar
a b 2
```

Comment: Nice. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

A solution without using awk (only for fun),

```
while IFS= read -r aline; do 
    echo "$aline" | tr " " "\n" | sort -r | tr "\n" " " ; echo ""; 
done < input | uniq -c
```

you get,

```
3 epd cvrA 
1 hofB emrY 
1 ydeP mdtI 
1 ygcH yagR 
1 nrdD abrB 
1 yqgD lsrK 
1 yiaF yhdA 
1 plsB fadJ 
1 thiG fadJ 
1 thiG plsB 
1 ybhS glnE 
1 yfeX idnR
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer maintains the field ordering, and also the line ordering:

```
awk '
  $1 FS $2 in count {count[$1 FS $2]++; next}
  $2 FS $1 in count {count[$2 FS $1]++; next}
  {
    count[$1 FS $2] = 1
    line[NR] = $1 FS $2
  }
  END {
    for (i=1; i<=NR; i++) 
      if (i in line) 
        print line[i], count[l[i]]
  }
' file
```

outputs

```
epd cvrA 3
emrY hofB 1
mdtI ydeP 1
ygcH yagR 1
nrdD abrB 1
lsrK yqgD 1
yhdA yiaF 1
fadJ plsB 1
fadJ thiG 1
plsB thiG 1
ybhS glnE 1
yfeX idnR 1
```

Comment: Nice. Thanks for the answer.